# How to close accordion by default

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm faceing problem in accordion.I'm using Bootstrap Accordion. I want all the panel closed by default, but my panels are start expanded.

whats wrong in my code?

```
 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse_ONE" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Example
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse_ONE" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <!-- nested -->
                                <div class="panel-group" id="nested" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
 <div class="panel panel-default">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                <a id="e1R" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#nested" href="#collapseOne">
                                                    .................
                                                </a>
                                            </h4>
                                        </div>
```

Hello

```
                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                <a id="e2R" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#nested" href="#collapseTwo">
                                                    --------------
                                                </a>
                                            </h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                             Hello
                                 </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

```
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: you have same id for two different elements. Dont use same id for different elements

Comment: you can set the radio button value using jquery `$("#radio_1").prop("checked", true);`

Comment: ok i'm changed id's.

Comment: Name also should be change for radio button in second group. You can't select more than one radio button with the same name applied. Change to  `quality[22]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like said, name should be change, here the working example. Try this :

```
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="q128" name="quality[21]" value="1" />1</label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="q129" name="quality[21]" value="2" />2</label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="q128" name="quality[22]" value="1" />1</label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="q129" name="quality[22]" value="2" />2</label>
</div>
```

**JS**

Applied for 1st div

```
$('div').first().on('click', '[type="radio"]', function () {
// put this `[type="radio"]:first  here ^ for first radio only
  var radioValue = $(this).val();
  $(this)
  .closest('div')
  .next()
    .find('[type="radio"]')
    .not('[value="' + radioValue + '"]')
     .prop('checked', true);
});
```

Applied for all div(**updated**)

```
$('div').on('click', '[type="radio"]:first', function () {
  var radioValue = $(this).val();
  $(this).closest('div').siblings().find('[type="radio"]').not('[value="' + radioValue + '"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/92xt2rh6/)**

Comment: OP asked for click of only the first radio,not every radio click

Comment: i'm afraid OP want references in first `DIV` rather than `first radio button in first div`..

Comment: @NavyaPrasad : then all two div have this function for first radio button. I thought for first div only

Comment: i changed id's in above my code.Please once check it

Comment: No need for id's in this case. See updated answer and demo

Comment: did't get it. you mean if select first radio in first div then second radio in second div will check, same applied if select second radio in first div, like that? Check this link http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/92xt2rh6/

Comment: @Norlihazmey Ghazali:I'm faceing problem in accordion.I'm using Bootstrap Accordion. I want all the panel closed by default, but my panels are start expanded.how to share my code?

Comment: something wrong with the code. Just open new question.

Comment: @Norlihazmey Ghazali:Hi,how to create dynamic accordion in jquery

Comment: What you mean by dynamic?

Comment: I'm created one accordion with two sub accordions by statically.But now,i created on table in DB.In that table 3 names,so now i want 3 sub accordions create automatically.In my table having 3 accordions so it requires 3 accordions.In case table having 10 names so 10 accordions automatically create.It is possible?

Comment: @Norlihazmey Ghazali:It is possible?

Comment: Possible. What you need to do is get all the data inside those mentioned table, and get it length. Loop over the sub accordian with length values. eg : table `product` having 5 data(name), get it length and loop by it length

Comment: @Norlihazmey Ghazil:Hi,

How to retrieve data from one database to another database using jQuery.I have two js files.First js page contains on db and second one contains another db.

Comment: Post another question, and we will assist you

Comment: I'm trying Ask Question but that page blocked my acct fro 3days.

Comment: Yes. you should wait. Cause others people whose facing the same problem with yours existed out there.

Comment: @Norlihazmey Ghazil:Hi,i'm faceing one problem how to solve it.I have four accordions left side two(LHS1,LHS2) and right side two(RHS1,RHS2) accordions.Now i'm opened LHS1 then RHS1 also open automatically.Now i'm opened LHS2 then RHS2 open automatically in LHS2 opening time top of LHS1 is collapsed but RHS1 is not collapsed.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this.,

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
var val = $(this).val();
$(this).closest('div').siblings().find('[type="radio"]').not('[value="' + val + '"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<label>
<input type="radio" data-id="q128" name="quality[21]" value="1" /> 1
</label>
<label>
<input type="radio" data-id="q129" name="quality[21]"  value="2" /> 2
</label>
</div>
<div>
<label>
<input type="radio" data-id="q128" name="quality[22]" value="1" /> 1
</label>
<label>
<input type="radio" data-id="q129" name="quality[22]"  value="2" /> 2
</label>
</div>
```

---

its works with your html structure

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
$('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);
var val = $(this).prop('checked', true).val();
$(this).closest('div').siblings().find('[type="radio"]').not('[value="' + val + '"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<label>
<input type="radio" id="LHS_1" value="1" /> 1
</label>
<label>
<input type="radio" id="LHS_2" value="2" /> 2
</label>
</div>
<div>
<label>
<input type="radio" id="RHS_1" value="1" /> 1
</label>
<label>
<input type="radio" id="RHS_2" value="2" /> 2
</label>
</div>
```

I hope this will helps you:)

Answer (score 0):

First make all names different ,[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o0u02haw/)

```
  <div>
    <label>
    <input type="radio" id="q128" name="quality[21]" value="1" /> 1
    </label>
    <label>
    <input type="radio" id="q129" name="quality[22]"  value="2" /> 2
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>
    <input type="radio" id="q128" name="quality[23]" value="1" /> 1
    </label>
    <label>
    <input type="radio" id="q129" name="quality[24]"  value="2" /> 2
    </label>
  </div>
```

And add this jQuery

```
$("input:radio").first().click(function () {
    if ($("input:radio").first().is(':checked')) {
            $("input:radio").attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
});
```

Comment: first i select any radio button in first div after automatically opposite value select in second div. And i select any button in second div after automatically opposite value select in first div.

Comment: @NavyaPrasad i have eedited the answer for you and added a demo

Comment: Hoooo, i selected first radio button after all radio buttons are selected.

Comment: No no no,I select any value after select opposite value.It means 1--2 and 2--1 in two div's.Are you understand?

Answer (score 0):

I'm faceing problem in accordion.I'm using Bootstrap Accordion. I want all the panel closed by default, but my panels are start expanded.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse_ONE" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Example
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse_ONE" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <!-- nested -->
                                <div class="panel-group" id="nested" style="margin-bottom:0px;">

                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                <a id="e1R" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#nested" href="#collapseOne">
                                                    .................
                                                </a>
                                            </h4>
                                        </div>

                                        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                            <div class="panel-body">

                                               Hello


                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                <a id="e2R" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#nested" href="#collapseTwo">
                                                    --------------
                                                </a>
                                            </h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                            <div class="panel-body">

                                              Hello


                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

what is the mistake?